# Gaussian filtering using Gaussian function in matlab

Tags: matlab, filter, fft, gaussian

I am trying to filter a signal using a Gaussian function.

This is the code I have come up with.

```
clear all
x = -1:0.001:1;
y = sin(2*pi*x/0.4) + sin(2*pi*x/0.1);

yh = fft(y);
plot(abs(yh))
del = 0.1;
g = (6/(pi*del^2))^0.5*exp(-6*x.^2./del^2);
gh = fft(g);

yfilter = ifft(2*pi*yh.*gh);
plot(x,y)
hold on
plot(x,yfilter);
```

However, when I do this the amplitude of the filtered signal blows up. Is this normal? If not what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal is amplified because the filter is not normalized. You can check with `plot(abs(gh))` (or better `plot(fftshift(abs(gh)))`) that its frequency response has a large magnitude.

To avoid this you should normalize the filter. There are several possible ways to do it. For example, to achieve unit gain for zero frequency use

```
g = g/sum(g);
```